# Using the URLconf defined in Django tried these URL patterns in this order:

Tags: python, django

I have a django app. And some upload functionality.

The page with the upload function is loading correcttly.

But after I do a submit. I get this errror:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/

Using the URLconf defined in schoolfruitnvwa.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/

The current path, main/, didn’t match any of these.
```

so this is the views.py

```
from .forms import ProfileForm
from .models import UploadFile


# Create your views here.
""" def store_file(file):
    with open("temp/hello.png", "wb+") as dest:
        for chunk in file.chunks():
            dest.write(chunk) """


class CreateProfileView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = ProfileForm()
        return render(request, "main/create_profile.html", {
            "form": form
        })

    def post(self, request):
        submitted_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if submitted_form.is_valid():
            uploadfile = UploadFile(image=request.FILES["upload_file"])
            uploadfile.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")

        return render(request, "main/create_profile.html", {
            "form": submitted_form
        })
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.CreateProfileView.as_view())
]
```

forms.py:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.Form):
    upload_file = forms.FileField()
```

So my question is: what I have to change?

I try it like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('main/', include('main.urls', namespace='main')),
   
]
```

But then I cant run the app:

```
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.
```

in urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name='main'

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.CreateProfileView.as_view())
]
```

main urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('main/', include('main.urls', namespace="app_main")),
   
]
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main',
    
]
```

and so the structure looks like this:

the manage.py is in the folder: schoolfruitnvwa. and in the folder schoolfruitnvwa I have the main application.

Comment: it seems to me that it does not find  templates. Usually they are placed in the templates folder => the folder with the name of the application(templates/sample). And they write the path to the example like this: "sample/create_profile.html", where sample is the folder which has the same name as the application.

Comment: Share full error traceback. Also share both project's and app's urls.py files.

Comment: try setting in urls.py app_name = 'main'

Comment: @mightycodeNewton Only try it like this `path('main/', include('main.urls')`, then you type the requested url as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/` then it will go to main's app urls.py where you have `path("", views.CreateProfileView.as_view())`.

Comment: @inquirer Yes, that's also a way and called Template name spacing.

Comment: Well, you need to write `namespace="main"`.

Comment: yes, ofcourse I also tried that:   path('main/', include('main.urls', namespace="main")),

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Using the URLconf defined in schoolfruitnvwa.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    main/

The empty path didn’t match any of these.

Comment: @mightycodeNewton you have multiple applications?

Comment: just one app with name main

Comment: @mightycodeNewton Share entire project structure, seems there's a problem in schoolfruitnvwa.urls. Well what is this `schoolfruitnvwa`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must check the url defined in the urls.py (this files is located near your settings.py) of your project and add. Be careful Django got urls.py files I can't be a bit disturbing at the start.

In urls.py (near settings.py): :

```
path('main/', include('youappname.urls', namespace="app_namespace")),
```

In urls.py (of your app):

```
app_name = 'yourappname'

urlpatterns = [
    path(...your api function call...),
]
```

Comment: I edit the post. But so the application is running. But if I press the button upload then I get the error

Comment: Yep in your urls.py (the one where you defined your api call you must add) app_name = "yourappname" just before your urlpattern = [..]

Comment: Oke, I did that. I can run the application. But then  if I go to: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ I get this error: 
Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Using the URLconf defined in schoolfruitnvwa.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    main/

The empty path didn’t match any of thes

Comment: @mightycodeNewton Will you share the project structure? And `INSTALLED_APPS` from settings.py file. It would be better if you share image of error as Its not understandable through exception.

Comment: This is because none of your url are bind to your adress only, two solutions or you remove 'main/' in urls.py projects, or you check at 127.0.0.1:8000/main/

Comment: Yes, oke, But the error occured when I trigger the function post. So in the beginning the app is running fine. so is this correct?   return HttpResponseRedirect("/main") in the post method

Comment: so after post the url has to be: http://127.0.0.1:8000 without main.

Comment: Well you have several method to redirect, my favorite is return redirect("yourappname:function_name") but you can also decided to return render("html_page_name.html")

Answer (score 0):

ohhh, in the html file there was standing: /main/

```
  <form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %} {{ form }}
      <button type="submit">Upload!</button>
    </form>
```